# Add more than one checkbox when install with Wix is over

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.7

I have an setup for my C# application. At the end of setup I added a checkbox proposing to launch application. It works good. But i'm unable to add a second checkbox proposing to launch an optional installer.

There is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?define compagny = "myCompagny"?>
<?define product = "myProduct"?>
<?define version = "!(bind.FileVersion.MyProject.exe)"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*"
           Name="$(var.product)"
           Language="1033"
           Version="$(var.version)"
           Manufacturer="$(var.compagny)"
           UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"/>
    <Icon Id="icone.ico" SourceFile="$(var.MyProject.ProjectDir)\Images\icone-VR.ico"/>
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico"/>
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyProject.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="$(var.product)" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
      <ComponentRef Id ="ApplicationShortcut"/>
      <ComponentRef Id ="ApplicationShortcutDesk"/>
    </Feature>

    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf"
                 Value="..\license.rtf"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp"
                 Value=".\Resources\WixUIBannerBmp.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp"
                 Value=".\Resources\WixUIDialogBmp.bmp"/>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch $(var.product)" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Warning. If you don't have optionnal package, consider to install it."/>

    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#MyProject.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
               Control="Finish" 
               Event="DoAction" 
               Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
  </Product>

  [...]
 </Wix>
```

How can I add another CheckBox to launch `./Resources.myOptionalPackage.exe` ?

If I can't add another checkbox, can I add a new dialog page used to install the feature ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create own edited UI with custom dialog.

1.First go to official [GIT repository](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib) and copy files `WixUI_Minimal.wxs` and `ExitDialog.wxs` , or copy whole repository and find files locally. Create own copies of this files to you project/Solution and rename them for example to `WixUI_Custom.wxs` and `MyExitDialog.wxs` .

Replace content of new files too, for `WixUI_Minimal.wxs` replace

`<UI Id="WixUI_Minimal">` to `<UI Id="WixUI_Custom">`,

for `ExitDialog.wxs` replace

`<Dialog Id="ExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">` to `<Dialog Id="MyExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">`

and both

`<Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" Overridable="yes" />` to `<Show Dialog="MyExitDialog" OnExit="success" Overridable="yes" />`

2.Change `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>` in your Product to `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Custom"/>`

3.Now you installer should open with exact UI as before, but from your classes

4.Open `WixUI_Custom` and change

`<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">` to `<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">`

so UI will open our new Dialog.

5.Open `MyExitDialog.wxs` and add new Control block, as it is already present

```
<Control Id="OptionalCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="135" Y="190" Width="220" Height="40" Hidden="yes" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT]">
  <Condition Action="show">
    WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT AND NOT Installed
  </Condition>
</Control>
```

Change identificator `Id` to anything, `X`,`Y` for new position in dialog, `Property` for new property, in which will be checkbox value stored and `Text` for new property, in which will be displayed text stored. Place Text property to Condition too, so display will depend on text property set, as in existing checkbox.

```
<Control Id="SecondCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="135" Y="220" Width="220" Height="40" Hidden="yes" Property="WIXUI_SECONDCHECKBOXVALUE" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGSECONDCHECKBOXTEXT]">
  <Condition Action="show">
    WIXUI_EXITDIALOGSECONDCHECKBOXTEXT AND NOT Installed
  </Condition>
</Control>
```

6.Now you can do the same things with new Checkbox as with existing using new properties defined in new Control.

Comment: Thank you ! I have to solve step 6 (my second check box calls the first one, probably because second `CustomAction` point on `WixShellExecTarget`) but it's another problem.

Comment: Maybe if you know the answer I asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465862/unable-to-launch-exe-in-wix-setup, I can't call the .exe that I want